# Empty li's text on button click

Tags: jquery, dom

Generated output is as follows:
HTML

```
<div id="resultCancel" class="error" style="display: block;">
    <a class="close">X</a>
    <ul style="">
        <li for="ProductId" generated="true" class="error" style="">Please Enter License Key</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to empty the contents of the li when you click the a.close (before anyone kills me, we're using an old code base which is why I'm using the .live funciton)

```
$('a.close').live('click',function(){
   $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast");
   $(this).closest//.next//.sibling('ul').addClass('foo');
});
```

by using closest I can go up the DOM tree, I need to go down. .next and .sibling are having no effect.... If it matters the div#resultCancel is triggered by jQuery validation plug in.

Comment: If the `li` is contained by the div that's being faded out, why do you need to alter it in some way?  What version of jQuery are you using?  `.next` or `.sibling` seem like they should work to me.

Comment: using 1.6.4, I think i can get .next to work. I need to alter it because if it displays the error message from the server, and is re-submitted with a blank value it is displaying the server error msg, not client side IE Please enter a value etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.next()`

```
$this.next('ul').find('li.error').addClass('foo').html('Text Changed!!')
```

Use `.on()` instead of `.live()` as the latter is **deprecated**..

```
$('a.close').on('click',function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   //$this.parent().fadeOut("fast");
   $this.next('ul').find('li.error').addClass('foo').html('Text Changed!!')
});
```

Also you need `not change the text` as you are `hiding the parent div`.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bK6X8/)**

For **Dynamic elements delegate the event**

```
$('body').on('click','a.close',function(){  // jQuery > 1.7.0

$('body').delegate('a.close' ,'click',function(){  // jQuery < 1.7.0
```

Comment: Please read my post (before anyone kills me, we're using an old code base which is why I'm using the .live funciton)

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign You should use `.delegate` if it is an older version of jQuery. Note that the signature provided in this post will not work if it is dynamic element.

Comment: How do I get it to work if it's dynamic. What is happening is if you enter a license key in the text box that is invalid, you get a message from the server "not cancelled license $$$ does not exist" if you then  empty the text box and hit submit again, the same error is displayed from the server, whereas it should be client side "Please enter a license #"